# What's the difference between a Euchre, a March and a Set?

Tags: euchre

I've heard of different terms for the same result in Euchre, but is it just preference or is there more to it?

- **Call trump and get all 5 tricks:** Is this called a "March" and/or a "Euchre"?
- **Earn 3 or more tricks when the opposing team calls trump:** Is this "Setting Them" and/or "Euchring Them"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Calling and getting all five tricks is **A March**.
- Calling trump and failing to get 3 tricks is called a **Euchre**.

This is the earliest reference I could find to Euchre, in [Hoyle's 1845 edition](http://books.google.com/books?id=bz8VAAAAYAAJ&dq=The%20Game%20of%20Euchre&pg=PA259#v=onepage&q=The%20Game%20of%20Euchre&f=false).

[image: Euchre]
[image: A March]

This excerpt is from [The Law and Practice of the Game of Euchre](http://books.google.com/books?id=azmZ0tWYeicC&dq=The%20law%20and%20practice%20of%20the%20games%20of%20euchre&pg=PA17#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Charles Henry Wharton Meehan.  Written in 1862, per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euchre#Origins), it is believed to be the oldest book dedicated to Euchre.

[image]

[Hoyle's 2001 edition](http://books.google.com/books?id=n_tD6dmWpxUC&lpg=PT167&dq=euchre&pg=PT165#v=onepage&q=euchre&f=false) uses the same terms, as does [Scarne's Encyclopedia of Card Games](http://books.google.com/books?id=La7J1XQk1bAC&lpg=PA236&dq=euchre&pg=PA237#v=onepage&q=euchre&f=false).  Card Games for Dummies does as well, however they use the terms "Marches or Sweeps" for getting all five tricks.

While I've heard the other two terms, it does not seem that they have entered common enough usage to be documented into any formal listing of rules.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I've understood it:

- **Calling trump and getting all 5 tricks** -- that is called a "March", although I've heard it called "getting a Euchre" which I feel is wrong, because of below.
- **Earn 3 or more tricks when opposing team calls trump** -- If your opponent calls trump, and you get 3 or more tricks, you have "euchered" or "set" them, and they have been "set" or "euchred".  These are used interchangably from what I've ever seen.